# Doxygen style mainpage for Maven

Tags: java, maven, doxygen

We have an API for OSX that we offer in 3 different languages; 
Objective-C, C++, and Java.

For the C++ and The Objective C Languages we use Doxygen for all of the documentation. The same nice looking presentation that is applied to the class pages is also provided for the examples page (mainpage.h). I especially like the syntax coloring.

For the Java Language, we are using Maven. Since apple's dev environment doesn't really offer much for Java, we can use Maven for both documentation and its a decent build system as well. The class pages look as good as Doxygen in my opinion, but the presentation of the main examples page(examples.apt), looks pretty plain and uneventful.

Ive been searching for any reference on how to add some color to the page, but haven't really found anything.

My question:

Can anyone provide an example of how to implement coloring in the appropriate .apt file(examples.apt) or the sites.xml file?

Comment: Are really stuck with .apt ? Why not using markdown ? Furthermore which site skin are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main locations for customizing the Javadocs.  The first in in the pom.xml files.  The second location is in the src/main/javadoc directory.  You will probably have to create the src/main/javadoc directory yourself since it isn't normally in the initial set of directories.

See https://github.com/BradleyRoss/tutorials for how I set up some Javadoc settings.  Look at the pom.xml in the parent module and the src/main/javadoc directory in tutorials-common module.

See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/stylesheet-configuration.html for information on how to replace the stylesheet.css file with your own.  That is probably where most of the color selection would go.  It uses the stylesheetfile and stylesheet tags in the configuration section for the Javadoc plugin.

Maven apparently uses a modified version of the stylesheet.css file that comes with the JDK.  You may want to compare the JDK and Maven versions to get some ideas on what you can change.

Comment: It turns out we had more problems than this. The resource folder wasn't even writing to the sites directory. We discovered we neglected to add the version number for the site plugin in the pom file. Once we did this, all the functionality started to come together. We were then able to add the maven-fluido-skin to the sites.xml without getting any build errors, and we now have syntax coloring. It all looks much better.